# Rails 4: applying different layouts to specific controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ruby-on-rails-4, layout

In my Rails 4 app, I have a PagesController, with a `app/views/layouts/pages.html.erb` layout.

Two pages need a specific layout: `home` and `help`.

To apply a specific layout to `home`, I did the following:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render :layout => 'homepage'
  end
end
```

and I have a specific homepage layout: `app/views/layouts/homepage.html.erb`

This works perfectly.

Then, I tried to replicate this process for the help page:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render :layout => 'homepage'
  end
  def help
    render :layout => 'helppage'
  end
end
```

and I have a specific helppage layout: `app/views/layouts/helppage.html.erb`

However, the help page does not take the desired layout.

Is there something wrong with my code?

—————

**UPDATE**: as per Adrian Mann's request, here is my full `PagesController`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:help]

  def home
    [...]
    render :layout => 'homepage'
  end

  def features
  end

  def pricing
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

  def feedback
  end

  def press
  end

  def help
    render :layout => 'helppage'
  end

  def privacy
  end

  def terms
  end

  def career
  end

  def help
  end

  def faq
  end

  def guides
  end

  def support
  end

  def investors
  end

end
```

and here is my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # include Pundit

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # after_action :verify_authorized, :except => :index

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :time_zone, :company_type, :expert, :expert_approval, :category, :description, :portfolio, :price, :avatar, :first_reference, :second_reference, :third_reference, :location) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company_name, :email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation, :time_zone, :company_type, :expert, :expert_approval, :category, :description, :portfolio, :price, :avatar, :first_reference, :second_reference, :third_reference, :location) }
  end

  def user_for_paper_trail
    user_signed_in? ? current_user.try(:id) : "Unknow User"
  end

  def facebook_copy_link(string)
    require "uri"
    array = URI.extract(string.to_s)
    array.select { |item| item.include? ( "http" || "www") }.first
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your full application controller file please and your FULL pages controller?

Comment: Absolutely. Please see the **UPDATE** section in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: nit-pick: don't put a require in a method. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, note the removed `render`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    layout "homepage"
  end
  def help
    layout "helppage"
  end
end
```

Or:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  layout "homepage", only: [:home]
  layout "helppage", only: [:help]

  def home
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

As stated [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128130/1945948):

> The method `render` will actually attempt to render content; you
>   should not call it when all you want to do is set the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this gives me the following error: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    layout: 'homepage'`.

Comment: @ThibaudClement Sorry, I have edited the question, removed the `:` and expanded on my answer a bit. Please try the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in your code. Which layout do you see for `help` action? Can you try `layout false`?

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  def home
    render :layout => 'homepage'
  end
  def help
    render :layout => 'helppage'
 end
```

end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The layout I get for the `help` action is the general one I built for all other actions of the controller. I get the same result when I try `layout false`

Comment: I also tried to rename the `helppage.html.erb` to `xyz.html.erb` in case there was a naming convention causing an error of some sort, but it did not change anything.

Comment: what happens if you use `homepage` layout for `help`? Maybe helppage layout itself has some code issue.

Comment: Good idea. Just tried to use homepage layout. But same result: the general layout is applied. This would suggest that the problem may not come from the layout itself, but from the `render` method, wouldn't it?

Comment: I may have found the root cause of the issue. If I apply the helppage layout to any other action in the controller, it works. So I tried to understand what was unique about the `help` action and realized that I had `before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:help]` in my controller. Could this prevent the layout from being rendered?

Comment: I tried to comment out `before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:help]`but got the same result, so it may not be the problem in the end.